# Using Reportbuilder for Delphi, is it possible to print landscape and portrait within the same report?

Tags: delphi, printing, reportbuilder

We're using Reportbuilder for Delphi and I have a report, made up of several smaller subreports, set up to print landscape. Is there a way to make the first subreport print in portrait, whilst the others print landscape?

I have tried setting the orientation on the TppReport PrinterSetup object before it prints and this seemed to work at first, however it caused problems with printing the report, and exporting it to PDF.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't played too much with Report Builder, but I suggest you try FastReports http://www.fast-report.com/en/, the price is perfect, the features are perfect, has built in scripting capabilities -- which will allow you to achieve this goal and many other!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. In report design for main, uncheck `ParentPrinterSetup` for the sub reports.

[image]

Set `poLandscape` or `poPortrait` in `PrinterSetup` for the sub report from the sub report tab.
[image]

Tested with ReportBuilder 12.03, Delphi XE and Foxit 4.1.1

**Edit 1**
Also tested with D2007 and ReportBuilder 10.07. No and problem printing to pdf with first subreport as portrait and second subreport as landscape.

Here is the dfm containing the report definition I tested with.

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 176
  ClientWidth = 377
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ppReport1: TppReport
    PrinterSetup.BinName = 'Default'
    PrinterSetup.DocumentName = 'Report'
    PrinterSetup.PaperName = 'A4'
    PrinterSetup.PrinterName = 'Default'
    PrinterSetup.mmMarginBottom = 6350
    PrinterSetup.mmMarginLeft = 6350
    PrinterSetup.mmMarginRight = 6350
    PrinterSetup.mmMarginTop = 6350
    PrinterSetup.mmPaperHeight = 297000
    PrinterSetup.mmPaperWidth = 210000
    PrinterSetup.PaperSize = 9
    AllowPrintToFile = True
    DeviceType = 'Screen'
    EmailSettings.ReportFormat = 'PDF'
    OutlineSettings.CreateNode = True
    OutlineSettings.CreatePageNodes = True
    OutlineSettings.Enabled = True
    OutlineSettings.Visible = True
    TextSearchSettings.DefaultString = '<FindText>'
    TextSearchSettings.Enabled = True
    Left = 112
    Top = 32
    Version = '10.07'
    mmColumnWidth = 0
    object ppDetailBand1: TppDetailBand
      PrintHeight = phDynamic
      mmBottomOffset = 0
      mmHeight = 30692
      mmPrintPosition = 0
      object ppSubReport2: TppSubReport
        UserName = 'SubReport2'
        ExpandAll = False
        NewPrintJob = False
        OutlineSettings.CreateNode = True
        ParentPrinterSetup = False
        PrintBehavior = pbSection
        TraverseAllData = False
        mmHeight = 5027
        mmLeft = 0
        mmTop = 5292
        mmWidth = 197300
        BandType = 4
        mmBottomOffset = 0
        mmOverFlowOffset = 0
        mmStopPosition = 0
        object ppChildReport2: TppChildReport
          PrinterSetup.BinName = 'Default'
          PrinterSetup.DocumentName = 'Report'
          PrinterSetup.PaperName = 'A4'
          PrinterSetup.PrinterName = 'Default'
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginBottom = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginLeft = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginRight = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginTop = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmPaperHeight = 297000
          PrinterSetup.mmPaperWidth = 210000
          PrinterSetup.PaperSize = 9
          Version = '10.07'
          mmColumnWidth = 0
          object ppDetailBand3: TppDetailBand
            mmBottomOffset = 0
            mmHeight = 13229
            mmPrintPosition = 0
            object ppLabel2: TppLabel
              UserName = 'Label2'
              Border.BorderPositions = []
              Border.Color = clBlack
              Border.Style = psSolid
              Border.Visible = False
              Caption = 'Label2'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clBlack
              Font.Name = 'Arial'
              Font.Size = 12
              Font.Style = []
              Transparent = True
              mmHeight = 4868
              mmLeft = 10054
              mmTop = 3440
              mmWidth = 12785
              BandType = 4
            end
          end
        end
      end
      object ppSubReport1: TppSubReport
        UserName = 'SubReport1'
        ExpandAll = False
        NewPrintJob = False
        OutlineSettings.CreateNode = True
        ParentPrinterSetup = False
        PrintBehavior = pbSection
        TraverseAllData = False
        mmHeight = 5027
        mmLeft = 0
        mmTop = 18256
        mmWidth = 197300
        BandType = 4
        mmBottomOffset = 0
        mmOverFlowOffset = 0
        mmStopPosition = 0
        object ppChildReport1: TppChildReport
          PrinterSetup.BinName = 'Default'
          PrinterSetup.DocumentName = 'Report'
          PrinterSetup.Orientation = poLandscape
          PrinterSetup.PaperName = 'A4'
          PrinterSetup.PrinterName = 'Default'
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginBottom = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginLeft = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginRight = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmMarginTop = 6350
          PrinterSetup.mmPaperHeight = 210000
          PrinterSetup.mmPaperWidth = 297000
          PrinterSetup.PaperSize = 9
          Version = '10.07'
          mmColumnWidth = 0
          object ppDetailBand2: TppDetailBand
            mmBottomOffset = 0
            mmHeight = 13229
            mmPrintPosition = 0
            object ppLabel1: TppLabel
              UserName = 'Label1'
              Border.BorderPositions = []
              Border.Color = clBlack
              Border.Style = psSolid
              Border.Visible = False
              Caption = 'Label1'
              Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
              Font.Color = clBlack
              Font.Name = 'Arial'
              Font.Size = 12
              Font.Style = []
              Transparent = True
              mmHeight = 4868
              mmLeft = 11906
              mmTop = 2646
              mmWidth = 12785
              BandType = 4
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Unfortunately I tried this in our setup (ReportBuilder 10.04, Delphi 2006) and whilst all the settings were there and accepted the values - it didn't actually change the page orientation on the child reports. Any chance you could make the code for your example report available to me so I can compare it with the report layout I have here, see if any differences might be affecting it (beyond the version difference)? - Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Kieran - Tested with 10.07 in D2007. Added dfm for report definition.